# How to display values from one and the same table with a difference of one year?

Tags: sql

There is a table containing the date of the study patients.

```
select inspection_date from inspection
```

Study of the patient is done not regularly with a random period of time. 
You want to display in a single line the information about the first study and study that was closest to the patient via the first study +1 year.

Comment: I do?  I really want to display that?  If so, I would start with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  patient, firstStudy, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 inspection_date, 
                    ABS(DATEDIFF(s,DATEADD(y,firstStudy,1),inspection_date)) AS diff FROM inspection
        WHERE patient=myPatientsFirstStudy.patient
        ORDER BY diff
        ) AS studyClosestAfterYear
FROM    (SELECT patient, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 inspection_date FROM inspection
                 WHERE patient=myPatientsWithStudy.patient
                 ORDER BY inspection_date
                ) AS firstStudy
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT patient FROM inspection
             ) AS myPatientsWithStudy
        ) AS myPatientsFirstStudy
```